# Microsoft Outlook 2011 constantly crashing

Tags: macos, ms-office

I just purchased Microsoft Office 2011 for Mac last week. Outlook CONSTANTLY crashes. I have tried everything… uninstall and re install twice, rebuilding main identity. Please help! I am so frustrated since I just purchased this. I am running Mountain Lion as well.

Here is the error when it crashes:

```
Microsoft Error Reporting log version: 2.0

Error Signature:
Exception: EXC_CRASH (SIGTRAP)
Date/Time: 2013-02-15 20:20:24 +0000
Application Name: Microsoft Outlook
Application Bundle ID: com.microsoft.Outlook
Application Signature: OPIM
Application Version: 14.2.0.120402
Crashed Module Name: merp
Crashed Module Version: 2.2.4.120402
Crashed Module Offset: 0x00003aa2
Blame Module Name: OutlookCore
Blame Module Version: 14.2.0.120402
Blame Module Offset: 0x0004de5f
Application LCID: 1033
Extra app info: Reg=en Loc=0x0409
Crashed thread: 8
```

New error after taking MERP update and Office update 14.2.5:

```
Microsoft Error Reporting log version: 2.0

Error Signature:
Exception: EXC_CRASH (SIGTRAP)
Date/Time: 2013-02-18 16:36:46 +0000
Application Name: Microsoft Outlook
Application Bundle ID: com.microsoft.Outlook
Application Signature: OPIM
Application Version: 14.2.5.121010
Crashed Module Name: merp
Crashed Module Version: 2.2.4.121010
Crashed Module Offset: 0x00003aa2
Blame Module Name: OutlookCore
Blame Module Version: 14.2.5.121010
Blame Module Offset: 0x0004e10d
Application LCID: 1033
Extra app info: Reg=en Loc=0x0409
Crashed thread: 8
```

Took SP3 for Outlook so now using version 14.3.1 and new error:

```
Microsoft Error Reporting log version: 2.0

Error Signature:
Exception: EXC_CRASH (SIGTRAP)
Date/Time: 2013-02-18 17:39:05 +0000
Application Name: Microsoft Outlook
Application Bundle ID: com.microsoft.Outlook
Application Signature: OPIM
Application Version: 14.3.1.130117
Crashed Module Name: merp
Crashed Module Version: 2.2.4.130117
Crashed Module Offset: 0x00003782
Blame Module Name: OutlookCore
Blame Module Version: 14.3.1.130117
Blame Module Offset: 0x0004d9ed
Application LCID: 1033
Extra app info: Reg=en Loc=0x0409
Crashed thread: 8
```

Comment: You tagged your question with Mountain Lion and mentioned Microsoft Office despite your title mentioned Outlook. OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion Gatekeeper feature may cause problems with your app.

Comment: There is a bug that is throwing licence verification errors, reinstall and then update all the way to [14.2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d260944-0d77-4fb7-9699-f2bf00132d07) and see if that works EDIT: I see from the error that you are already @ 14.2 and change. I will edit more when i find a further answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the crashlog it looks like Merp is causing the crash.  I googled merp crashing outlook and came across an article on answers.microsoft.com.  From what it said, you need to update Microsoft Error Reporting Program (Merp) from Here:   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=28734.

Before you do that, check and see if you have any rules that may be corrupt and remove them.

Here's the link about Merp crashing outlook:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macoutlook/outlook-2011-crashes-every-time-i-open-rules/8740225f-9b4b-4df7-a1e1-f693fb12322f?msgId=655b76b4-28af-4df0-b5e5-56989f26677e

Comment: I updated MERP and also took the Office 14.2.5 Update as well. It is still crashing. Here is the error now:

Answer (score -4):

Hey I had the same issue with my computer. I wasted my time on it for
many days but finally I got a solution from this link
http://www.microsoftliveassist.com/cant-verify-the-signature-install-error-in-office-2013/

Comment: Links may break in the future which is why we prefer answers which summarize the essential part of the referenced site.